# Python sorting, limiting the print of result

Tags: python, sorting

I want to print entries from a twitter log in order of dates.  I did manage to sort them in order of dates but I can't figure out how to show the recent/top 100 list

Here's the code:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('hoge_qdata.tsv','r', 'utf-8') as tweets:
    tweet_list = tweets.readlines()
    print tweet_list.pop(0).strip()

paired_tweets = sorted([ (int(t.split('\t')[2]), t) for t in tweet_list ], reverse=True)
for p in paired_tweets:
    print p[1].encode('utf-8').strip()
```

Data file is provided below... http://web.sfc.keio.ac.jp/~t12102ti/isc/tweetsample.zip

Comment: `for p in paired_tweets[:100]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use python array slices:

```
for p in paired_tweets[:100]:
    print p[1].encode('utf-8').strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

To access only the first `n` entries in a list, use a slice:

```
first_n_entries = my_list[0:n]
```

For example:

```
names = ['Dan', 'Joe', 'Greg', 'Molly']
print names[0:3]
>>> ['Dan', 'Joe', 'Greg']
```